# Telegram bot error on Raspberry PI

Tags: python, bots, urllib, telegram

I've designed a long time ago a homemade window controller on a Raspberry PI interfaced with a Telegram bot and it all seemed to go okay until some days ago when this error continues to happen. After I reboot the program it works for some time (usually hours) before this error comes up again.

Can someone help me understand what this problem might be? I'm not very familiar with Python and its libraries to be honest.

Thank you in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 331, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 333, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1172, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 313, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 371, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 745, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 617, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 516, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _make_request
    self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % read_timeout)
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=50)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1059, in get_from_telegram_server
    allowed_updates=allowed_upd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 876, in getUpdates
    return self._api_request('getUpdates', _rectify(p))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 434, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/telepot/api.py", line 130, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 135, in request_encode_body
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 153, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 579, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 579, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 579, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    _pool=self, _stacktrace=stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 265, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error)
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot489425943:botname/getUpdates (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=50)",))
```

Here's my code

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import pifacedigitalio as p
    import time
    from time import sleep
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import datetime
    import sys
    from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
    import telepot
    from telepot.namedtuple import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

    #Inizializzo PiFace
    p.init()
    TapparelleIsOpen = 0 #0 se chiuse, 1 se aperte
    FinestreIsOpen = 0
    Automatic = 1 #1 se automatico, 0 se manuale

    allowed = [id1,id2] #al posto dello zero metti l'id di Sara

    #Mostra "Auto si" se la modalità automatica è disattivata, "Auto no" se la modalità automatica è attivata
    default = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
                [KeyboardButton(text=('Auto ' + ('si' if Automatic == 0 else 'no'))),KeyboardButton(text="Manual")], 
                [KeyboardButton(text="Info")],
                ])

    prevInTemp = 0.0 
    prevOutTemp = 0.0 
    prevRadSol = 0
    prevWindSpeed = 0.0 
    prevRain = 0.0

    TOKEN = ‘bot_token'

    def on_chat_message(msg): #definizione bot telegram
        global TapparelleIsOpen
        global FinestreIsOpen
        global Automatic
        content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
        command = msg['text'].lower()
        print (command,' ', chat_id)

        if chat_id in allowed:
            if command == 'start':
                keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
                           [KeyboardButton(text=('Auto ' + ('si' if Automatic == 0 else 'no'))),KeyboardButton(text="Manual")],
                           [KeyboardButton(text="Info")],
                           ])
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Menù principale', reply_markup=keyboard) 

            if command == 'auto si' or command == 'auto no':
                if (Automatic == 1):
                    Automatic = 0
                else:
                    Automatic = 1
                keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
                           [KeyboardButton(text=('Auto ' + ('si' if Automatic == 0 else 'no'))),KeyboardButton(text="Manual")],
                           [KeyboardButton(text="Info")],
                           ])
                text = 'Modalità automatica ' + ('<b>attivata</b>' if Automatic == 1 else '<b>disattivata</b>')
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id,text,reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode = 'HTML')

            if command == 'manual':
                string = ('Apri' if FinestreIsOpen == 0 else 'Chiudi') + ' finestra'
                string2 = ('Apri' if TapparelleIsOpen == 0 else 'Chiudi') + ' tapparella'
                keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
                           [KeyboardButton(text=string),KeyboardButton(text=string2)],
                           [KeyboardButton(text="Torna indietro"),KeyboardButton( text="Reset")],
                           ])
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id,'Comandi manuali, scegli azione',reply_markup=keyboard)

            if command == 'reset':
                reset()


            if command == 'apri finestra' or command == 'chiudi finestra':
                if (FinestreIsOpen == 1):
                    chiudiFinestre()
                else:
                    apriFinestre()
                string = ('Apri' if FinestreIsOpen == 0 else 'Chiudi') + ' finestra'
                string2 = ('Apri' if TapparelleIsOpen == 0 else 'Chiudi') + ' tapparella'
                keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
                           [KeyboardButton(text=string),KeyboardButton(text=string2)],
                           [KeyboardButton(text="Torna indietro")],
                           ])
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id,'Finestra ' + ('aperta' if FinestreIsOpen == 1 else 'chiusa'),reply_markup=keyboard)

            if command == 'apri tapparella' or command == 'chiudi tapparella':
                if (TapparelleIsOpen == 1):
                    chiudiTapparelle()
                else:
                    apriTapparelle()
                string = ('Apri' if FinestreIsOpen == 0 else 'Chiudi') + ' finestra'
                string2 = ('Apri' if TapparelleIsOpen == 0 else 'Chiudi') + ' tapparella'
                keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
                           [KeyboardButton(text=string),KeyboardButton(text=string2)],
                           [KeyboardButton(text="Torna indietro")],
                           ])
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id,'Tapparella ' + ('aperta' if TapparelleIsOpen == 1 else 'chiusa'),reply_markup=keyboard)

            if command == 'torna indietro':
                keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
                                       [KeyboardButton(text=('Auto ' + ('si' if Automatic == 0 else 'no'))),KeyboardButton(text="Manual")],
                                       [KeyboardButton(text="Info")],
                                       ])
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Menù principale', reply_markup=keyboard)

            if command == 'info':
                keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
                                       [KeyboardButton(text=('Auto ' + ('si' if Automatic == 0 else 'no'))),KeyboardButton(text="Manual")],
                                       [KeyboardButton(text="Info")],
                                       ])
                mex = 'La tapparella è:  ' + ('<b>aperta</b>' if TapparelleIsOpen == 1 else '<b>chiusa</b>')+'\nLa finestra è : '+('<b>aperta</b>' if FinestreIsOpen == 1 else '<b>chiusa</b>') + '\nLa temperatura esterna è: ' + '<b>' + str(getOutsideTemp(html)) +   ' °C</b>' + '\nLa radiazione solare è: ' + '<b>' + str(getSolarRadiation(html)) +   ' W</b>' + '\nLa velocità del vento è: ' + '<b>' + str(getWindSpeed(html2)) +   ' km/h</b>' +  '\nLa temp interna giù è: ' + '<b>' +  str(getInsideTemp(html)) + ' °C</b>' + '\nLa temp interna su è: ' + '<b>' +  str(getInsideTemp2(html)) + ' °C</b>' + '\nModo automatico: ' + ('<b>attivo</b>' if Automatic == 1 else '<b>disattivo</b>')
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, mex, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode = 'HTML')

    bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
    bot.message_loop({'chat': on_chat_message})

    def getHour(): #funzione che rileva l'ora
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        orario = now.hour + (now.minute/100)
        return orario

    def getInsideTemp(tmp): #funzione che rileva la temperatura interna
        insidetemp = tmp[3].string
        if (insidetemp == 'n/a'):
            return prevInTemp
        else:
            if len(insidetemp) == 6:
                insidetemp = float(insidetemp[0] + insidetemp[1] + insidetemp[2] + insidetemp[3])
            elif len(insidetemp) == 5:
                insidetemp = float(insidetemp[0] + insidetemp[1] + insidetemp[2])
        prevInTemp = insidetemp
        return insidetemp

    def getInsideTemp2(tmp): #temp interna da sensore aggiuntivo 
        sensor = W1ThermSensor()
        insidetemp2 = sensor.get_temperature()
        return insidetemp2+0.5

    def getOutsideTemp(tmp): #funzione che rileva la temperatura esterna
        outsidetemp = tmp[1].string
        if (outsidetemp == 'n/a'):
            return prevOutTemp
        else:
            if len(outsidetemp) == 6:
                outsidetemp = float(outsidetemp[0] + outsidetemp[1] + outsidetemp[2] + outsidetemp[3])
            elif len(outsidetemp) == 5:
                outsidetemp = float(outsidetemp[0] + outsidetemp[1] + outsidetemp[2])
        prevOutTemp = outsidetemp;
        return outsidetemp

    def getSolarRadiation(tmp): #funzione che rileva le radiazioni solari
        radsol = tmp[12]
        if len(str(radsol)) == 90:
            return prevRadSol
        if len(str(radsol)) == 93:
            radsol = int((str(radsol)[37]))
        elif len(str(radsol)) == 94:
            radsol = int((str(radsol)[37] + str(radsol)[38]))
        elif len(str(radsol)) == 95:
            radsol = int((str(radsol)[37] + str(radsol)[38] + str(radsol)[39]))
        elif len(str(radsol)) == 96:
            radsol = int((str(radsol)[37] + str(radsol)[38] + str(radsol)[39]) + str(radsol)[40])
        prevRadSol = radsol
        return radsol

    def getWindSpeed(tmp): #funzione che rileva la velocita' del vento
        windspeed = tmp[56].string
        if (windspeed == 'Calm'): #se il vento e' zero, la pagina lo mostra come "Calm"
            prevWindSpeed = 0.0
            return 0.0
        elif (windspeed == 'n/a'):
            return prevWindSpeed;
        else: #vari filtri per eventuali diversi ordini di grandezza del vento
            if (len(windspeed) ==  6):
                wind = float(windspeed[0])
            elif (len(windspeed) == 8):
                wind = float(windspeed[0] + windspeed[1] + windspeed[2])
            elif (len(windspeed) == 9):
                wind = float(windspeed[0] + windspeed[1] + windspeed[2] + windspeed[3])
        prevWindSpeed = wind
        return (wind)

    def getRain(tmp):
        line = tmp[18].string
        if (line == 'n/a'):
            return prevRain
        else:
            rain = float(line[0] + line[1] + line[2])
        prevRain = rain
        return rain

    def reset(): #reset del telecomando
        pushButton2(0)

    def apriFinestre(): #algoritmo che apre le finestre
        global FinestreIsOpen
        if (FinestreIsOpen != 1):
            pushButton(4)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(3)
        FinestreIsOpen = 1

    def apriFinestreNotte(): #algoritmo che apre le finestre per la notte
        global FinestreIsOpen
        if (FinestreIsOpen != 1):
            pushButton(4)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(3)
        FinestreIsOpen = 2

    def chiudiFinestre(): #algoritmo che chiude le finestre
        global FinestreIsOpen
        if (FinestreIsOpen != 0):
            pushButton(4)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(1)
        FinestreIsOpen = 0

    def apriTapparelle(): #algoritmo che apre le tapparelle
        global TapparelleIsOpen
        if (TapparelleIsOpen != 1):
            pushButton(4)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(5)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(3)
        TapparelleIsOpen = 1


    def chiudiTapparelle(): #algoritmo che chiude le tapparelle
        global TapparelleIsOpen
        if (TapparelleIsOpen != 0):
            pushButton(4)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(5)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(1)
        TapparelleIsOpen = 0


    def chiudiTapparelleSpiraglio(): #algoritmo che chiude le tapparelle solo in parte
        global TapparelleIsOpen
        if (TapparelleIsOpen != 0):
            pushButton(4)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(5)
            pushButton(7)
            pushButton(1)
            sleep(30)
            pushButton(2)
        TapparelleIsOpen = 0



    def pushButton(x): #funzione che preme il pulsante "x"
        global p
        p.digital_write(x,1)
        sleep(0.25)
        p.digital_write(x,0)
        sleep(0.75)


    def pushButton2(x): #funzione che preme il pulsante "reset"
        global p
        p.digital_write(x,1)
        sleep(4.25)
        p.digital_write(x,0)
        sleep(0.75)



    #Main Program
    while(1):

      try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(‘link').read() #prelevo la pagina
        print('Success')
        time.sleep(15)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser') #effettuo il parsing
        html = soup.find_all(width= '170') #ricerco tramite chiave
        html2 = soup.find_all(width='100')

        if Automatic == 1: #se siamo in modalità automatica

            if(getHour() >= 21.35 and getHour() <= 23.59 or getHour() >= 00.00 and getHour() <= 10.00 or getHour() >= 14.00 and getHour() <= 16.30  ): #orari banditi
                time.sleep(100)

            elif (getHour() > 10.00 and getHour() <= 10.05): #apro le tapparelle automaticamente tutti i giorni
                if (TapparelleIsOpen == 0):
                    for persona in allowed:
                        bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi buongiorno! Ho aperto le tapparelle', reply_markup=default)
                    print('ho aperto le tapparelle, buongiorno')
                apriTapparelle()
                print(getHour(),'ho aperto le tapparelle, buongiorno')
                time.sleep(60)

            else: #orari consentiti

                if ((getOutsideTemp(html) <= 0 and getSolarRadiation(html) <= 100 and getHour() >= 15.30)): #ho aggiunto un check orario senn le chiude di mattina
                    if (TapparelleIsOpen == 1):
                        for persona in allowed:
                            bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi! Ho chiuso le tapparelle, fa freddo',reply_markup=default)
                        print("ho chiuso le tapparelle, fa freddo")
                    chiudiTapparelle()
                    print (getHour(),'ho chiuso le tapparelle, fa freddo')


                if (getInsideTemp2(html) >= 25 and getSolarRadiation(html) >= 550):
                    if (TapparelleIsOpen == 1):
                        for persona in allowed:
                            bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi! Ho chiuso le tapparelle a spiraglio, troppo sole',reply_markup=default)
                        print("ho chiuso le tapparelle a spiraglio, troppo sole")
                    chiudiTapparelleSpiraglio() # qui ho aggiunto la chiusura non completa con il pulsante stop e un timer affinché entri un po' di luce
                    print (getHour(),'ho chiuso le tapparelle a spiraglio, troppo sole')


                if (getHour() >= 17.00 and getSolarRadiation(html) <= 300 and getSolarRadiation(html) > 0):
                    if (TapparelleIsOpen == 0):
                        for persona in allowed:
                            bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi! Ho aperto le tapparelle, poco sole',reply_markup=default)
                        print("ho aperto le tapparelle, poco sole")
                    apriTapparelle() 
                    print (getHour(),'ho aperto le tapparelle, poco sole')


                if (getWindSpeed(html2) >= 15):
                    if (FinestreIsOpen == 1):
                        for persona in allowed:
                            bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi! Ho chiuso le finestre, troppo vento',reply_markup=default)
                        print("ho chiuso le finestre, troppo vento")
                    chiudiFinestre()
                    print (getHour(),'ho chiuso le finestre, troppo vento')


                if (getInsideTemp(html) <= 20):
                    if (FinestreIsOpen == 1):
                        for persona in allowed:
                            bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi! Ho chiuso le finestre, fa freddo in casa',reply_markup=default)
                        print ("ho chiuso le finestre, fa freddo in casa")
                    chiudiFinestre()
                    print (getHour(),'ho chiuso le finestre, fa freddo in casa')


                if (getWindSpeed(html2) < 15 and getRain(html) == 0 and getSolarRadiation(html) != 0): 
                    if(getInsideTemp2(html) > 25 and getInsideTemp2(html) > (getOutsideTemp(html)+1)):
                        if (FinestreIsOpen == 0):
                            for persona in allowed:
                                bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi! Ho aperto le finestre per far entrare aria fresca',reply_markup=default)
                            print("apro le finestre per far entrare aria fresca")
                        apriFinestre()
                        print (getHour(),'apro le finestre per far entrare aria fresca')
if (getInsideTemp2(html) > 25 and getInsideTemp2(html) < (getOutsideTemp(html)-1)):
                if (FinestreIsOpen == 1):
                    for persona in allowed:
                        bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi! Ho chiuso le finestre, fuori fa caldo',reply_markup=default)
                    print("chiudo le finestre, fa caldo fuori")
                chiudiFinestre()
                print (getHour(),'chiudo le finestre, fa caldo fuori')


            if (getSolarRadiation(html) == 0):
                time.sleep(600) #ho messo il timer a 10min
                print("tra poco chiudo le finestre, fuori e' buio")
                print("tra poco chiudo le tapparelle, fuori e' buio") 
                if (FinestreIsOpen == 1):
                    for persona in allowed:
                        bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi! Tra poco chiudo le finestre, fuori fa buio',reply_markup=default)
                    chiudiFinestre()
                    print (getHour(), 'ho chiuso le finestre, fuori è buio')
                    time.sleep(45)

                if (TapparelleIsOpen == 1):
                    for persona in allowed:
                        bot.sendMessage(persona,'Ehi! Tra poco chiudo le tapparelle, fuori fa buio',reply_markup=default)
                    chiudiTapparelle()
                    print (getHour(),'ho chiuso le tapparelle, fuori è buio')
                    time.sleep(45)

                if (getWindSpeed(html2) < 15 and getRain(html) == 0): 
                    if(getInsideTemp2(html) > 25 and getInsideTemp2(html) > (getOutsideTemp(html)+1)):
                        apriFinestreNotte()
                        print (getHour(),'apro le finestre per la notte')


            time.sleep(900)

    else:
        time.sleep(60) 

  except Exception as e:
     print('Fail' + str(e))
     time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please provide minimum code, don't just copy and paste it.

Comment: The point is I don't actually know what exactly causes the problem, if it's some error on urllib.request or with the telepot library